# delete multiple records using array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need a procedure for delete multiple rows in multiple tables by passing array set of values in parameters

Consider 3 tables:

```
student_master(id,student_name);
subject_master(id,subject_name);
marks(id,student_id,student_id,subject_id,marks)
```

here in parameter 
for e.g student id will be: a['1','3','7','15']

What is the procedure for this criteria?

Comment: From which tables do you want to delete the rows? To which IDs do those values relate to? And why are you passing numbers as strings?

Comment: by passing student id i want to delete all the data related to that student id. from other tables(subject and marks) i need just pass a id's in array.

Comment: Do you use [foreign keys](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-fk.html)? If so, how did you [define them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)? `ON DELETE CASCADE` can help you a lot in your case.

Comment: @pozs & a_horse thanks for your solution

Answer (score 20):

If your `student_id` s are integer or bigint then use without quote:

```
delete from marks
where student_id = ANY(Array [1,3,7,15])
returning student_id
```